# Trouble during building step of MPI for python

Tags: python

I am a bit stuck during the building process of the MPI python v 1.2.2 installation. Specifically, I get the following error message:

```
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1/Python/Versions/7.1/Python: Not a directory
warning: build_exe: building extension "python2.7-mpi" failed
warning: build_exe: command '/usr/bin/mpicc' failed with exit status 1
```

I checked the directory and it does not exist. What does exist is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1`. I am unsure why the directory seems to tack on those last bits after the first '7.1'. Is there a way to specify the actual directory during the building process?

[This website](http://mpi4py.scipy.org/docs/usrman/install.html) does list some options but I am not sure which one I should pick. I am fairly new to this all so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any one of them should work, the one which seems the easiest is:

```
$ python setup.py build --mpicc=/where/you/have/mpicc
```

So you would simply run

```
$ python setup.py build --mpicc=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.1
```

Assuming that is where mpicc is located.

Does this help?

Comment: Yes, this was very helpful. As silly as this sounds, I actually did not realize that should be the path!!

Comment: :P believe me, I've done faaar stupider things. Glad to be helpful! :)

Comment: If this solves your problem well enough, feel free to accept the answer (click on the outlined check-mark underneath the vote counter).